# How force Selenium to not wait for page to load

Tags: selenium-ide

I am building a test suite for a web application using Selenium IDE ver 2.5.0 in Firefox ver 27. The problem I am encountering is that some urls I am testing do not return any HTML content AT ALL. These are servlets that 'say nothing' if the correct data is not posted to them. It seems that Selenium gets stuck indefinitely on these urls when testing. That is, when the test is ran, the step that deals with that page (either a verifyText, or whatever) hangs forever and stops dead the test being ran. I have tried 'setTimeout', 'waitFor{thing}'. None of these make any difference. As it stands all the urls where this happens are untestable. Does anyone know of some workaround, or other Selenium-friendly technique to force the tool to not wait for content to be sent back from the server? I am preferring to not jump into Java and do all this from that standpoint. So my question is:
Is there a way to force Selenium IDE to not wait for the server to respond in any way. And if so, fail that step.

Here is an example of it getting stuck. In this example, it hangs on the third row/item:

```
    <tr>
    <td>setTimeout</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>${base_url}/someServlet</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=h2</td>
    <td>SomeText</td>
    </tr>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working around this by converting all my tests to Java side Selenium WebDriver code. The test no longer gets suck indefinably on those spots that it did before. This was not an ideal solution, but it did stop the hanging test issue. Below is an example of code from the test:

```
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get(baseUrl + "/?SomeParam=x");

    assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.linkText(LOG_IN_TEXT)));
```